# What is $\mathbb{Z_2^2}$?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

What is $\mathbb{Z_2^2}$?

Is it the Cartesian product $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{4}$?

Comment: The title doesn't match the question...

Comment: Yes, exactly. Say it's a $2$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbf F_2$.

Comment: It is not, however, a finite field.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_2=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, and for any group $G$, $G^2=G\times G$, so $\mathbb Z_2^2=(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)\times (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: No, is the product $\Bbb{Z_2}\times\Bbb{Z_2}$

Comment: Can you give context?  I'd assume it is $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$  ($\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$) but I'm not certain without context.

Comment: Is isomorphic to GF(4)?

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z_2}$ = {0,1}

Comment: @GabrielFanini  it's not even an integral domain:  $(0,1)$ is a zero divisor

Comment: $\mathbb{Z_2^2}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F_4}$?

Comment: @Gabriel Fanini: it is the "Klein 4-group". Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group

Comment: This question is so harmless. It is absolutely unclear why a bunch of Oberlehrers took the pain  to close it. Instead of the closing operation plus $12$ comments a two line answer would have served the OP optimally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's the Cartesian product $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, where $ \mathbb{Z}_2 $ is the finite field with two elements. However, $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ isn't a field under the induced operations, as $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ have no multiplicative inverse.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z_2^2}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F_4}$?

Comment: They are isomorphic under addition, but they have different mutliplicative structures.